# What am I missing in these plaidML instructions?

Tags: python, plaidml

I'm beginning to feel like a complete idiot. I'm trying to build plaidML from scratch following [these instructions](https://plaidml.github.io/plaidml/docs/building.html).

First step, install Anaconda. Already installed. No problem.

Second, install bazelisk. Took me a while to successfully install wget so I could then follow these instructions, but OK. Got bazelisk installed.

Third, "Configure the Build". WHA????

It's asking me to run a script called ./configure. Where in the above steps was that created? There's no such script. Looking at the sample output, it appears that at this point I'm supposed to have a plaidML source directory, $HOME/src/plaidml. When in the instructions was that supposed to have been created?

The first line of the sample output mentions PlaidML, so it seems that this configure script is PlaidML-specific, and that it must have come with the source. But nowhere on this page does it actually tell me where the source is.

I have been searching for any page that tells me where to actually download the source and create this directory, but so far to no avail. What am I missing?

Edit: Are these instructions assuming that I have cloned the entire plaidML master github repository? [This thing?](https://github.com/plaidml/plaidml)

Comment: “*Are these instructions assuming that I have cloned the entire plaidML master github repository?*” It’s not clear where you would expect to be building from if you didn’t have a copy of the source code from their repository.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm pretty new to many aspects of this, including git. I found it odd that the instructions for building from source didn't include any instructions for where to find the source.  I did in fact clone the entire repository, but that includes many packages besides the one I'm interested in, and for all I know it includes multiple branches as well (I am a git newbie as I said). So it seems like overkill to me to take the entire repository.  But anyway, that worked (up to a point, it doesn't actually build). I appreciate the response.